# Special characters in League of Legends username

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to change my name and instead of it being 'MoZed', let's say, I'd like it to be 'ΜοZed'. You might ask me what's the difference so I'll answer that now. The 'Mo' in the first name are typed with English characters while in the second one with Greek ones.

Long story short, I would like to put some Greek characters in my name.

According to this [article](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752814-Summoner-Name-FAQ) I should be able to do so, since I'm on the EUW server, but for some reason every time I try to I either get the error "Unfortunately your desired name is not available.", even though I checked and none has the one I want, or "Your desired name has too many characters." even though it doesn't exceed any limits.

This article even though it's less than 6 months old, it doesn't apply on League anymore?
Am I doing something wrong or should I ask Riot for some help?

Comment: Note that it'll be very irritating for your friends trying to send you a message ingame with /msg

Comment: Pedantic comment - it's not English characters, it's Latin characters!

Comment: It's English and Greek. Not Latin.

Comment: the mordern English alphabet is a Latin alphabet consisting of 26 letters. now stop fighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an email to Riot support and asking them to change your name manually will do the job.

Apparently though, that can be done only once.

Answer (score 0):

The special charaters are saved in a special format which requires extra data to safe.

This extra data exceeds the maximum name length.

You should write riot a support ticket